# cannot get profile page using method GET?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, query-string

Im using Expressjs i want to show user input in URL after form submit and render user to profile page with name in URL so I use req.query and GET method.
 This is app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = process.env.port || 1001;

var app = express();

app.engine('.ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(morgan('dev'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('user', { name: ''}));

app.put('/profile', function(req,res){
    var name = req.query.name;
    res.render('profile/'+ name , { name: name });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var name = req.query.name;
    res.render('profile/:name' , { name: name});    
});


app.listen(port, function(err){ if(err) throw err; console.log('Server running On Port : ' + port)});
```

This is form user.js

```
<form action="/profile/<%= name %>" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button><a>Add</a></button>
</form>
```

This is profile page.

```
<h1>Hello <%= name %></h1>
<button><a href="/">Home</a></button>
```

Comment: I've been update my answer, If you still want to show user input in url: So url will looks like this: `localhost:1001/profile/user-input-name`

Comment: I've been updated my answer again, then you've 2 option, you need your url looks like this: `localhost:1001/profile/user-input-name` or like this: `localhost:1001/profile/?name=user-input-name`. That choice it's yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‍ Maybe you can try this code below:

**App.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = process.env.port || 3000;

var app = express();

app.engine('.ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('user', { name: ''}));

app.post('/profile', function(req,res){
    var { name } = req.body;
    res.render('profile', { name });
});

app.listen(port, function(err){ if(err) throw err; console.log('Server running On Port : ' + port)});
```

‍ And now your, `user.ejs` will looks like this code below:

**user.ejs**

```html
<form action="/profile/<%= name %>" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button><a>Add</a></button>
</form>
```

> If you want your url looks like this: `http://localhost:1001/profile?name=yourname` then you only need to change method `POST` to `GET`, on your `App.js` and on your `user.ejs` form method.

**Updated:** If you want to your url looks like this: `http://localhost:1001/profile/yourname`, than you can change your `/profile` route with this code below:

```js
app.get('/profile', function(req,res){
  const { name } = req.query;
  res.redirect('/profile/' + name.replace(/ /g, '-') );
});

app.get('/profile/:name', (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;
  res.render('profile', { name : name.replace(/-/g, ' ') });
})
```

> If you're using that route obove, **make sure**, in your `user.ejs` still using `GET` method.

I hope it can help you .

Comment: I know req.body works but I want to show user name in URL like name=Jay ! That's why I use req.query and GET method , do you know how can show usernam in URL ?

Comment: You only need to change method `POST` to `GET` in your `app.js` and in your `form` method.

Comment: This code just works for me dude Thanks a lot for this , i don't know how this works but its really help full

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks too for upvote and correct answer badge.